# Firebase Android : How to show specific child inside recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm a new developer and I don't know how to show a specific child on Firebase database inside Recyclerview or Listview.

this is my database:

[image: daatabase]

Pages child is the one that should be shown after clicking on testbook and I want to show it inside Listview or Recycleview.

Can you help me by showing some examples or methods that can be used, please?

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I used this method with "Books" but it is not working with "pages"